# Show that an abelian group of order $p^k$ and of type $(p^{k_1},\dots,p^{k_t})$ contains $p^t-1$ elements of order $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that an abelian group of order $p^k$ and of type $(p^{k_1},\dots,p^{k_t})$ contains $p^t-1$ elements of order $p$.

Could someone help me about this problem? Do we use the Sylow-Theorem?

Comment: Remember that an element $g$ of a group has order $m$ if and only if $g^m=e$ in the group but $g^d\ne e$ for every divisor $d$ of $m$. In this case, an element has order $p$ if and only if $g^p=e$ but $g^1\ne e$. Can you count how many elements satisfy the former equality? the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just count the number of elements of order $p$ in each factor then multiply--the fact that you have a direct product shows that in order for an element to be of order $p$ it is necessary and sufficient that each factor have order dividing $p$ and that at least one has order exactly $p$. But then since each factor is cyclic, any element of order $p$ is a $p^{k_i-1}$th power of the generator, hence there are $p$ elements of order dividing $p$ at each factor, giving $p^t$ elements of order dividing $p$ in all, and subtracting $1$ for the identity completes the proof.